# Problem including a file in PHP via absolute path

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm having a trouble deploying my website. I've been building it under Windows, with WAMP and now I'm deploying to Linux.

Code like this works on Windows:

*req.php*

```
echo "This is req<br>";
ini_set("include_path", "/home/clash/public_html/:".get_include_path());
require "/req1.php";
```

*req1.php*

```
echo "This is req1";
```

But fails in the production environment with the message:

> Warning: require(/req1.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in /home/clash/public_html/req.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '/req1.php'
>   (include_path='/home/clash/public_html/:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in /home/clash/public_html/req.php on line 5

The path in ini_set is the path of the actual location of the website on the server filesystem.

I wouldn't like to avoid absolute paths as a library that I use relies on them somewhat.

I am sure that I'm missing something very simple here, but I can't figure out what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, `/` is the root of the filesystem, similar to `C:\` on Windows. Remove the leading `/` and it will work as expected.

Comment: Like I said, that's an option I wouldn't like to be left with because the framework I use generates this kind of include URLs. Is there a way to automatically prepend them with app path?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the hard-coded path separator with the `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant. That way you ensure that your value for `include_path` is cross-platform.